# how to create cookie inside an iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, cookies

I try my code at firefox, It works, but It does not work on chrome, chrome does not allow third party cookies, I want to create cookies with javascript inside an iframe, how can I manage this ? iframe's domain is not same with the parent , thank you

Comment: What does your code look like? Are the domains the same for the parent and the iframe?  Where are you testing it, as a local file or on a server?

Comment: @NaNpx parent and iframe is different

Comment: but both domains and code-bases under your control?

Comment: yes, I try to set cookies, as I searched, It is about p3p, but I still can not solve it

Answer (score 2):

The best way to interaction between parent window and iframe is postMessage. Browsers support: FF3+, IE8+, Chrome, Safari(5...), Opera10+. Take a look for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

```
/*Parent*/
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('some content', "http://child-domain");



/*Child*/
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
console.log(e.data)
//set cookies or other
}, false);
```

Comment: i have an embed code, that a client can add inside their websites

Comment: You can dynamically determine domain name in your javascript.